# get current file name from sublime_plugin.WindowCommand

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I develop plugin for `sublime text 3`. And want to get currently opened file path ...

```
absolute1 = self.window.view.file_name()
```

... where `self` is `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand`

But fail:

```
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'view'
```

Full code of plugin:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import re, os, os.path

class OpenrelCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

    def run(self):
        relative = sublime.get_clipboard()
        absolute1 = self.window.view.file_name()
        absolute2 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(absolute1), relative))
        self.window.open_file(absolute2)

    def is_enabled(self):
        return bool(sublime.get_clipboard().strip())
```

If `self` would be `sublime_plugin.TextCommand` I could get current file path without a problem:

```
fileName = self.view.file_name()
```

... but `self` must be `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand` because I want to use method `open_file` :

```
self.window.open_file(absolute2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the API (http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window). `self` is a window object. So you need to do `self.window.active_view()` to get the view.

Comment: I try it, but fail: `absolute1 = self.active_window().view.file_name()
AttributeError: 'OpenrelCommand' object has no attribute 'active_window'`

Comment: Woops sorry I mean `self.active_view()`

Comment: I'm sorry. `absolute1 = self.active_view().file_name()
AttributeError: 'OpenrelCommand' object has no attribute 'active_view'`

Comment: Man I'm just having issues today. haha. `self.window.active_view()`

Answer (score 6):

For Sublime Text 3 the command that worked for me was:

```
self.view.window().active_view().file_name()
```

Answer (score 2):

For sublime Text 3 i think using the following :

```
myCompleteName = self.view.file_name()
```

can be a solution,i've tried it with **sublime_plugin.TextCommand** and it works just fine