# Run external python script from Sublime Text passing active file as argument

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a some python script called spc.py somewhere on the disk, which is for processing text file in some way (and it uses more external libraries). Now I call it from console with passing a filename as argument.

Because I'm running this script often, during the editing the document itself, I would like to be able to call the script straight from the Sublime Text, passing active file as argument, so I can call it by one click without leaving the window.

But I haven't found a way how to call external python script from Sublime Text plugin. Can you give me a clue? Is that even possible?

Comment: I just posted an answer with 2 related solutions I've written.  I'm not sure exactly what you're attempting to do, as the question is slightly vague. If you update your question with a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll tailor the answer to your specific case.

Comment: @Enteleform You give me the right answers, because the real problem was than I didn't know how to get out from the internal Sublime Text python interpreter to my interpreter that I'm using. I've post the exact solution I have found according to your second recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of way to doing this is by calling python with arguments through cmd.exe using subprocess module, with sending the file name of active file as argument for python program.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import subprocess

class ExecuteExternalProgramCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        exec_file = "C:\Path\To\My\Program\spc.py"
        command  = ["cmd.exe", "/c", "python", exec_file, self.view.file_name()]
        subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Save it to your Sublime Text User plugins folder and then put keyboard shortcut to your User Keymap, for example

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+e"], "command": "execute_external_program"},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Create a [**custom build system**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126411/4955183) which accepts the current file as an argument.
- Create a [**plugin**](https://github.com/Enteleform/-SCRIPTS-/tree/master/SublimeText/%5BMisc%5D/%5BProof%20Of%20Concept%5D%20Execute%20Selection) which executes text from the current file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524926/get-current-file-name-from-sublime-plugin-windowcommand) to get the file name of the current sublime window. Now beyond that you just need a method that accepts a path as an input argument and from there do what you need to do.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import re, os, os.path

class OpenrelCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
    print self.active_view()
```